# How do I get the original ID of Content Page Control using JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

In my asp.net web application I am getting the `Texbox`'s ID using JavaScript like below

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function clearTextBox(textBoxID)
{
    document.getElementById('<% =RVTable.ClientID %>').value = textBoxID;
    alert(textBoxID.toString());
}
```

and I am storing that ID in HiddenField

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="RVTable" runat="server" />
```

Then I am retrieving the `TextBox`'s id using the below code in codebehind

```
  TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)FindControl(RVTable.Value.ToString());
  if (txtbox != null)
  {
      if (txtbox.ID.ToString() == RVTable.Value.ToString())
          txtbox.Text = (string)CheckBoxString.ToString();
  }
```

*For your reference I am doing all this in the Content Page*

Actually my requirement is that I have a few CheckBoxes and a few Textboxes in my project and one add button. I will check some CheckBox and then click on the textbox where the selected checkbox values has to display. Now if I click the Add button the selected CheckBox's values will be displayed in that TextBox. I am storing Clicked textbox's ID in the hidden Field.

Here is my pageLoad code the add OnClick attribute to textbox

```
txtRasi1.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
txtRasi2.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
txtRasi3.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
txtRasi4.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
txtRasi5.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
txtRasi6.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
txtRasi7.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
txtRasi8.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
txtRasi9.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
txtRasi10.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
txtRasi11.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
txtRasi12.Attributes["onclick"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";
```

I have achieved solution by using the above codes in a simple asp.net web application (when not using MasterPage).

But when I'm trying to use this same code in Content Page, the id of the clicked TextBox is coming like `ctl00_ChildPageContents_txtRasi3` instead of `txtRasi3` which is the original ID of the TextBox.

As I mentioned in the above code-behind code, the `FindControl()` did not find the clicked textbox since it gets different ID, `ctl00_ChildPageContents_txtRasi3`. How can I get the original ID `txtRasi3`?

I found one more problem also...[image]

Still txtbox object is null even though I  mentioned my TexBox's control ID directly in the `FindControl()` method.

Comment: Why are you using `ToString()` on a string instance (`name`)?

Comment: Actually the parameter of Findcontrol() is string.

Comment: But `name` *is* a string, you don't have to use ToString to get another string.

Comment: haa... i know that man... come on, can you give me solution for that problem.. below screenshot was tested by me...

Answer (score 1):

set the textbox client id mode to static ......

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: ctl00_ChildPageContents_txtRasi3 instead of txtRasi3

Comment: you set client id mode of ur txtRasi3 to TO static...like this  <asp:TextBox ID="txtRasi3"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox> i tried my self it working fine

Comment: Yes buddy I have tried as same you. But didn't works.... I am out of office now and will try it again.... If you don't  mistake me,can you give me you mail Id... If it doesn't work still I will mail you my code...